# Exported FBX file size is too big

Tags: modeling, export, .fbx

I have FBX model which is **~25MB** in size. When I import this model into a blender and export it again (even with decimation modifier applied), the exported FBX from blender increases in size to **~44MB** even when just straight export without any modifications is done. The model has no animations at all and I even exclude them in the export settings. Only the *MESH* and *OTHER* are being exported.

So I would like to know if something can be done in order to somehow preserve the exported model's size since it's not modified in any way after import, or at least do something to minimize the file size as much as possible when exporting?

I've also noticed when I combine all sub-meshes (Ctrl + J), exported fbx size will be increased to **~88MB**

[Link to Blend file](https://1drv.ms/u/s!AslK6TQ8d8WugjFOiiBoNZtzDcau)

Thx for any suggestions

Comment: Can you import the model into a blend file and add that blend file to your question?

Grab the URL of the question

Go to https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Select the blend file

Add the url of the question

Grab the url that results

Go back to the question and edit it to add the new url

Add the new url to the bottom of the post

Comment: Hey @MartyFouts, seems like I can't upload my blend file to blend exchange because it is too big so I changed the link to include only the .blend file